# Create a dictionary from an array but having an issue with key uniqness

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I receive an array of winners from the API. Each week i have 3 winners. So i wanted to use the week number in each winner as the keys of a dictionary to use them as the section name in a table view.

i tried `let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: winners.map{($0.weekNo, $0)})`
but because of the weekdays are not unique and i have 3 winners each week so i already have 3 winners in the winners array having the same week number.

How can i make a collection of these winners each 3 winners under a unique key "week number" `[String: Winners]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using the wrong API.

To *group* the array by week number use [init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: winners, by: {$0.weekNo})
```

The result is `[String: [Winners]]` rather than `[String: Winners]`

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary but you can put the keys in another variable and sort those.

Comment: i did it like this and the results are correct in the console `let dict = Dictionary(grouping: winners, by: {$0.weekNo}).sorted {(a, b) -> Bool in
                return Int(a.key)! > Int(b.key)!
            }`

Comment: Yes, it is, but now you have an **array of tuples**. And why do you create `Int`s from the week numbers in the `sort` closure?

Comment: Yes an array of tuples that's true...maybe i will do it the way you mentioned in another variable and sort. I used Ints because the week numbers are 12, 11, 10, 9 so when comparing it as strings they are not sorted correctly.

Comment: Don't do that, use `.sorted {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedDescending}`. This preserves the numeric order.